# Wi-Fi Tp-Link в локальной сети Mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik, firewall

Воткнул Wi-Fi (192.168.0.1/24) Tp-Link через WAN (Интернет через статический IP провайдера 172.18.64.10/24) в локальную сеть Mikrotik (172.18.64.0/24). Теперь клиенты Wi-Fi имеют доступ в локальную сеть Mikrotik. Как это заблокировать?
На TP-Link не смог сделать это правило. А на Mikrotik в Firewall правило работает только если с Wi-Fi выходить в интернет, а в локальной сети не работает (Например: 172.18.64.10 запрет на 172.18.64.120). Помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: *на Mikrotik в Firewall правило работает только если с Wi-Fi выходить в интернет, а в локальной сети не работает* Ну, значит, неправильно написано правило. *172.18.64.10 запрет на 172.18.64.120* Запрет чего именно? На Микротике на порте к роутеру - разрешить forward в WAN, разрешить input (любой или отдельные виды трафика), заблокировать всё остальное. До кучи можно с остальных клиентских портов запретить forward на порт с TP-Link.

Comment: *На TP-Link не смог сделать это правило.* А для тплинка локалка микротика - это интернет...

Comment: Я уже даже не указывал в правиле какой протокол запрещать, то есть весь трафик блокировал. Если конкретно указывать TCP или UDP, тоже не работает. Трафик всё равно проходит в локальную сеть из Wi-Fi.  Chain пробовал все (forward, input, output), Src. Address стоит 172.18.64.10, в Action - drop. Устройство на Wi-Fi получает по DHCP от Wi-FI адрес 192.168.0.100 и через NAT на Wi-Fi выходит с него уже с адресом 172.18.64.10, поэтому я этот адрес и блокирую на Mikrotik.

Comment: Wi-Fi у меня подключен не на прямую к Mikrotik, а через несколько неуправляемых коммутаторов...

Comment: Какая разница-то?

Comment: На одном физическом порту Микротика находятся около 30 устройств, которые соединены через неуправляемые коммутаторы. Выделять отдельный порт только для роутера проблемно. Сейчас понимаю, что сделать это (изолировать 172.18.64.10) не получится, так как запрос (например: ping 172.18.64.120) с роутера в локальную сеть идет сразу же на ближайшее устройство, а не в mikrotik, а потом уже на устройство.

Comment: Поэтому отключу NAT на роутере и буду заходить в локальную сеть с ip адресом от DHCP роутера (192.168.0.0/24). Подсеть 172.18.64.0/24 я уже с роутера не увижу, а в Микротике дам этой подсети интернет. Но пока разбираюсь "как дать ей интернет".

Comment: Если перевести роутер в режим моста и не отключить на нём DHCP, то клиенты локальной сети смогут получать с него адреса, что приведёт к проблемам.

Comment: Да, полностью согласен, поэтому я это не делаю. DHCP (192.168.0.0/24) раздается только клиентам роутера. С этим IP они через WAN попадают в локальную сеть. Сейчас на Микротике пытаюсь дать этой подсети интернет. На самом Микротике я уже вижу устройства с IP адресами 192.168.0.0/24

Answer (score 2):

В адреса на микротике добавь новый 172.18.65.1/24
. В роутере настрой статику 172.18.65.10/24. Фаервол начнет работать.

Вариант посложнее без новых адресов. Запретить форвард arp в фильтре бриджа. поставить на порт бриджа proxy-arp. Но возможны пропуски в неуправляемых комутаторах.